# How to use TextInputLayout without Theme.appcompat

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `TextInputLayout`, but I get a variety of errors due to missing style attributes because my app theme derives from **android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar** instead of **Theme.appcompat**. If I do derive the theme from **Theme.appcompat**, I lose action bars because my Activity derives directly from the native `Activity` instead of the `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`. If I derive from `ActionBarActivity`, I get the old support Action Bars, which are missing huge amounts of functionality compared to native **API 21** action bars. No way I can do that.

It seems bizarre that one can't use `TextInputLayout` in an actual Lollipop app that doesn't rely on the appcompat libraries. Presumably, the rest of the goodies in the new Design module aren't going to work either. :-(

Is there, by any chance, a list of style that must be defined in an app theme to use `TextInputLayout` in an activity that uses **Theme.Material**? I ended up adding about six or seven color declarations to my app theme (e.g. 
`android:colorControlActivated`,  `android:colorControlHighlight`, `android:TextColor`, &c), but the inflate exceptions keep on coming.

Or does anyone know of a replacement for for the Design library that provides a `TextInputLayout`? Or that just works in of **5.0 or 5.1+**?

Very bizarre. Material design is lovely. But I don't get why there aren't ANY native classes to support material design.

Comment: Is really that hard to google for "floating label android" yourself?

Comment: Thanks. Easy to google for it. But I was foolishly googling for TextInputLayout instead of "floating label android".  That answers the "Or does anyone know of a replacement part of the question?"

Comment: so you used float label, but not official TextInputLayout? I want to use TextInputLayout without appCompat

Comment: I ended up going the appCompat route in the end. There are various independent solutions available if you google, most of which are indifferently good. I did find one, but ended up buffing it up considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this type it never need the Theme.appcompat

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tv_metadata_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/tv_metadata_Details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Good solution. :-) Although I don't think that was available at the time I asked the question. Answer accepted.